# collapse and expanding groups for checkboxes

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox

I have a mysql query that gets displayed via PHP. Each returned record is assigned a checkbox. a column in the table (ReleaseNumber) has a number which groups the different records. How can I create collapseable groups of checkboxes by release number. I have attached an image of the current status and what I am after (outlook screenshot). The user can collapse or expand row groups. if a row group is selected all sub rows are also selected.

Can this be done and if so how?
Current:
[image]
Desired:
[image]

My Code is:

```
<?php
    mysql_connect("localhost", "username", "password")or die("cannot connect");    
    mysql_select_db("database")or die("cannot select DB");
    $sql="SELECT`despgoodsid` ,`crtd dept` ,`customer` ,`loc cust rel` ,`case no` ,`gross mass` ,`case width` ,`case length` FROM despgoods_alldetails WHERE transporttypename ='localjhb' AND locstatus ='unplanned' AND customer <>'customer' AND `loc cust rel` > 0 ";
    $result=mysql_query($sql);
    $count=mysql_num_rows($result);
    putenv("TZ=Africa/Johannesburg");

?>
<table border=0>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <form name="form1" method="post">
                <table border=0 id="hor-minimalist-a">
                    <tr>
                        <th>&nbsp;</th>
                        <th width=150><center>Release Number</th>
                        <th width=150>Dispatch Area</th>                        
                        <th width=150>Customer</th>  
                        <th width=130><center>Case Number</th>
                        <th width=80><center>Weight</th> 
                        <th width=80><center>Width</th> 
                        <th width=80><center>Length</th> 
                    </tr>
<?php
    while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
?>
                    <tr>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name=check[]  value="<?php echo $rows['despgoodsid']; ?>"></td>
                        <td><center><?php echo $rows['loc cust rel']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $rows['crtd dept']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $rows['customer']; ?></td>
                        <td><center><?php echo $rows['case no']; ?></td>
                        <td><center><?php echo $rows['gross mass']; ?></td>
                        <td><center><?php echo $rows['case width']; ?></td>
                        <td><center><?php echo $rows['case length']; ?></td>

                    </tr>                                   

<?php
    }
?>
                    </table>
                    <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan=3><input name="Next" type="submit" id="Next" value="Next"></td>
                    </tr></table>
```

Do I need some Java to complete this? any advice is appreciated as always?

Thanks and Regards,
Ryan Smith

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to achieve this. You'd don't need Java. You need Javascript.

The following jQuery functions should help you with this:

- http://api.jquery.com/hide/
- http://api.jquery.com/show/